# Reading a word and printing the number of vowels in the word. Java / Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to read a word from the user and print the number of vowels in that word. Any suggestions on how to read the word and print the number of vowels? Here is my code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountVowels
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String word = in.next();
      System.out.println("Please enter a word.");
      for (int w = 0;w < word.length();w++)
      {
         String ch = word.substring(i, i + 1);
         if ("aeiou".contains(ch))
         . . .
      }
      System.out.println("Vowels: " + "aeiou");
   }
}
```

This is another code below looks like it would work according to what I've learned in my beginner Java class but I can't get it to work on my platform because of the issue with my scanner class.

```
{
String word;
Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a word.");
word = myinput.next();
//This will convert your string to lowercase using toLowerCase() method.
char[] wordc = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
int vowels = 0; //This counter will count the vowels in the word.
for(int w = 0;w < word.length();w++) {
  if(wordc[w] == 'a' || wordc[w] == 'e' || wordc[w] == 'i' || wordc[w] == 'o' || wordc[w] == 'u') {
      vowels++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? How do your results vary from your expectations? Why does your last line count `consonants`? The assignment stops at `System.out.println("Vowels: " + . . .);` - where is that in your code? Also, `if ("aeiou".contains(wordc[w]))`

Comment: Please read my comment again, and ask a question; also, I will assume your code does not work how you expect. Tell us how it does not work. What input do you provide? What output do you get? What output do you expect? **Edit** your question. Without that information, no one can help you.

Comment: I'm not even able to enter input even with a simple scanner class project. Do you know of a better IDE to use for Java? I ran into issues using the scanner class for projects in Netbeans.

Comment: Netbeans is a serviceable IDE. **How** are you entering the word? We cannot see your screen, or what you are doing, or input you are providing. Also, is this the entirety of your program. Or are you using another `Scanner` somewhere and closing it before calling this code? If so, you also close `System.in` and you can't reopen it. If this is everything, then try eclipse I guess.

Comment: I have to try out eclipse because I get this error in Netbeans even with very simple projects with the scanner class and reading input. 

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to can solve the problem.

Read the input using `scanner.nextLine();`

Initialize a vowelCounter to zero, 'int vowelCounter = 0;"

Convert the string into a char array `word.toCharArray()`

Assign the vowels to a string `String vowels = "aeiou";`

Iterate through the char array and comparing if your vowel contains the current char, increment the counter

`if (vowels.contains(currentChar)){
     ++vowelCounter;
 }`

Then print the value of the vowelCounter. I'm sorry I can't post the full code, but I think understanding how to code works will aide you creating a different workable version.

Comment: @carnage47 So, what exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Do you know of a better free or simple IDE to use for Java? I have to use Netbeans for my Java class but I get issues with the scanner class even with simple projects so I'm not able troubleshoot the code correctly.

Comment: I've tested out the scanner class with very simple projects and I have successful builds but as soon as I enter this int line I get an error. I posted the error below. int theNumber = input.nextInt();

Comment: This is the error I get even though my code is correct.

> Task :run FAILED
Enter your age
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at NewProject.Main.main(Main.java:23)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @carnage47 That's weird... Try initializing the "theNumber" as `int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());`

Comment: I have code as simple as this but it still gives me an error this time saying "error: cannot find symbol
        int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());"

Here is the code that I have: 
        

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println(theNumber);

Comment: @carnage47 You initialized the declared the scanner as "input", so the correct way to access it would be; int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());